# What is the correct way of deploying a third-party UUPS upgradeable contract through gnosis-safe multisig?

Tags: gnosis-safe, safe-core

```
// Encode deployment data
const deployerInterface = new ethers.utils.Interface(CreateCallAbi);
const deployCallData = deployerInterface.encodeFunctionData("performCreate", [
    0,
    "bytecode",
]);

const ethAdapter = new EthersAdapter({
    ethers,
    signerOrProvider: deployerSigner,
});
const safeService = new SafeApiKit.default({
    txServiceUrl: "https://safe-transaction-goerli.safe.global",
    ethAdapter,
});

const txData = {
    to: "createCall contract address",
    value: "0",
    data: deployCallData,
};
const safeSdk = await Safe.default.create({
    ethAdapter: ethAdapter,
    safeAddress: SAFE_ADDRESS,
});
const safeTx = await safeSdk.createTransaction({
    safeTransactionData: txData,
});
const safeTxHash = await safeSdk.getTransactionHash(safeTx);

const signature = await safeSdk.signTypedData(safeTx);
console.log("txn hash", safeTxHash);

const transactionConfig = {
    safeAddress: SAFE_ADDRESS,
    safeTransactionData: safeTx.data,
    safeTxHash: safeTxHash,
    senderAddress: "---",
    senderSignature: signature.data,
};
console.log("tx config:", transactionConfig);

await safeService.proposeTransaction(transactionConfig);
```

Comment: Seems your have your code already, what is the exact problem?

Comment: The issue here is that the third party UUPS contract has constructor params and the createCall's performCreate method only takes some int values and deployCallData( bytecode ). I don't know how to incorporate those constructor params in "deployCallData" or through the "transactionConfig" in proposal submission step in the above code. Can you help me with that or provide some resources on how it can be done ?

Comment: The constructor params are part of the creation bytecode, and it works the same way as you'd deploy a contract from an EOA. They need to be included in the creation bytecode, read more here: https://medium.com/coinmonks/evm-part-ii-the-journey-of-smart-contracts-from-solidity-code-to-bytecode-a21300b23dee